# Betting with odds

Tags: odds-ratio, games, odds

I have a game where I can bet on two teams:

- One team has odds $1.7$
- The other has $1.5$

I understood that the one that pays off $1.5$ has an higher probability of victory, so it pays less. But how are these odds calculated?  How can I calculate the probability of victory for each team from these odds?

Answer (score 1):

We assume your bet is fair, and we denote $A$ as the event of team One winning, $B$ as the event of team two winning. The Fair Bet Odds Rule says:

> In a fair bet, the payoff odds equal the chance odds.

- Decimal odds

If $A$ happens your profit is $1.7-1=0.7$, if not your profit is $-1$. Assuming a fair bet we get:
$$0.7P(A)-(1-P(A))=0$$ and we get $1.7P(A)=1$ and $P(A)=\frac{10}{17}$. Similarly if $B$ happens you win $0.5$ and lose $1$ if it doesn't. The equation is thus
$$0.5P(B)-(1-P(B))=0$$ and we get $1.5P(B)=1$ and $P(B)=\frac{2}{3}$. We note that probabilities add up to more than 1 in this case since the bookmaker has to take its share.

- Pay off odds

In some settings you deal with payoff odds. "1.7 to 1" in this case is equivalent to decimal odd of $2.7$. In this scenario:

If $A$ happens you win $1.7$ if it does not happen you lose $1$. The equation is thus:
$$1.7P(A)-1(1-P(A))=0 $$ and $P(A)=\frac{10}{27}$, Similarly if $B$ happens you win 1.5 and lose 1 if it does not. The equation is thus $$1.5P(B)-1(1-P(B))=0$$ and $P(B)=\frac{2}{5}$. In this scenario your probabilities add up to less than one and the $difference\times stake$ is "the house percentage".

Special thanks to @Rodrigo de Azevedo for clarifying the difference between decimal and payoff odds.

Comment: Those probabilities do not add up to $1$.

Comment: Indeed, these do not add up. I am updating my answer with correct computations, I miscalculated everything

Comment: This is still wrong. If $A$ happens, you win $1.7 - 1 = 0.7$, not $1.7$.

Comment: I think we need to look at total payouts, and not at profit. If we follow the profit logic we get $0.7P(A)-1(1-P(A))=0$ and $P(A)=\frac{10}{17}$  similarly $0.5P(B)-1(1-P(B))=0$ and $P(B)=\frac{2}{3}$ and the sum of these probabilities add up to more than 1

Comment: If you don't consider profit, why $-1$ in the expected value? Note that the "probabilities" are the reciprocals of the odds. $1.7$ becomes $\frac{10}{17}$, for example. The "probabilities" add to more than $1$ because the bookmaker must make a profit.

Comment: $-1$ is the expected payout in case you lose. $1.7$ is the expected payout in case you win.  I thought that probabilities would add up to less than $1$ for the bookmaker to make profit. For example if you are playing  roulette and bet on colors, your probability of getting red is $\frac{18}{38}$, so is the probability of getting a black, with a probability of $\frac{2}{38}$ the ball is caught in a green pocket.

Comment: No. Suppose you bet 1 USD. Cost is 1 USD. If you win, you get 1.7 USD, which is revenue. Profit is 0.7 USD. If you lose, you get no revenue. Profit is -1 USD. Consider a football match, say, Real Madrid x Barcelona in some final. No chance of a draw. Equal chances of winning. Thus, odds are 2 and 2 if the bookmaker takes no cut. However, bookies must earn a living, so they reduce the odds to, say, 1.9 and 1.9. The "probabilities" become 52.6% for each team, which adds up to more than 100%, of course.

Comment: I still don't view this in terms of profit. The house takes your 1 dollar not as a cost to enter but as a guarantee of their due diligence in case they win. From Pitman's probability textbook:

Comment: Gamblers are concerned with another sort of odds, which must be distinguished from odds defined as a ratio of chances. These are the odds offered by a casino or bookmaker in a betting contract, called here payoff odds to make the distinction clear. If you place a  1 dollar  bet on an event A, and the payoff odds against A are 10 to 1, you stand to win 10 dollars if A occurs, and lose your 1  dollar if A does not occur. In a casino you first pay your 1 dollar. If A occurs you get back a total of 11 dollars. This is your winnings of 10 plus your 1 back.

Comment: this is from page 6 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4374-8)

Comment: Pitman is not using decimal odds! "10-to-1" is equivalent to decimal odds of 11. Take a look at [this](https://betting.betfair.com/decimal-odds-converter-fraction-odds-betfair-explained.html).

Comment: omg you are correct, i totally missed this. I am going to make a final amendment to my answer.